# How can I clean vocal microphone grill?

Tags: microphone

Every stage vocalist knows that excessive using of microphones leads to grill corrosion and clogging.

What is a fast and effective way of the microphone grill cleaning? Let it be Shure SM58 grill, but tips for other mics are welcomed as well :)

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [link to some advice directly from Shure](http://www.prosoundweb.com/article/properly_cleaning_your_microphones/).

It basically recommends removing the grill and windscreen and cleaning it with water and some mild detergent if necessary.

For the grille they recommend using a toothbrush with soft bristles to remove lipstick or other stuff stuck in the grille.

Answer (score 1):

I use the dishwasher.  Take out the foam insert and replace it when done.  Put the grill into the dishwasher with the dishes, don't tell your wife or GF. Don't leave it wet, I wrap in paper towels and shake well to get it really dry, re-insert the new foam inner piece and it is good to go!